# Uploading a file to Netsuite using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, npm, netsuite

So I am testing out a script that comes with an npm module that will upload a NetSuite file to the File Cabinet. 
<strike>Here is a link to the npm module called [nsupload](https://libraries.io/npm/nsupload). The instructions say to upload the Restlet included in the module to Netsuite and set the function in the RESTlet in the PUT method in Netsuite. When I run the script on my end to upload a file to the Netsuite File Cabinet I get the error "TypeError: sendToNetsuite is not a function."</strike>

Here is the test code the module supplies:

```
var sendToNetsuite = require('nsupload')
  .config({
    email: 'email',
    password: 'pass',
    account: 'account number',
    script: 'script number',
    method: 'PUT'
  });

sendToNetsuite('./foo.json', function(err, body) {
  console.log('Success!');
  console.log(body);
});
```

**EDIT:** 
I changed the npm module I was using to the one called [nscabinet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nscabinet). This stoo came with a sample code for uploading a file to Netsuite. Here's the code to that:

```
var nscabinet = require('nscabinet') ,
gulp = require('gulp') //or just vinyl-fs 


gulp.src('foo.js')
    .pipe(nscabinet({
        email : 'foo@bar.baz.com' ,
        password : '123456' ,
        account : '123456' ,
       // realm : 'sandbox.netsuite.com' ,
        //role : 3 ,
        rootPath : '/SuiteScripts',
        script : 'myuploadfile' ,
        deployment : 2
    }))
```

I left out a few parameters but I don't believe they make a difference. At the moment the error I keep getting is "SSS_INVALID_SCRIPTLET_ID - That Suitelet is invalid, disabled, or no longer exists." I have upload the Restlet that came with it to Netsuite as well but the problem persists.

Again, I have looked up the error but I still haven't figured out what the problem is. I tried testing the code within the code I wanted to use and by itself when it didn't work. Any ideas on solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to get the DL feature to work? I was with the CLI, but I want the wildcard * feature and doesn't appear possible with CLI

Comment: @nzaleski I never tested the download feature however the CLI didn't work for me. I wasn't sure why and since it wasn't necessary for me it wasn't a problem.

Comment: At this point, both libraries are no longer maintained, npm says that it they have security vulnerabilities, and Oracle has an official NetSuite SDK for NodeJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `script` option to the `script` id of the Restlet you uploaded to NetSuite.

```
gulp.src('foo.js')
.pipe(nscabinet({
    email : 'foo@bar.baz.com' ,
    password : '123456' ,
    account : '123456' ,
   // realm : 'sandbox.netsuite.com' ,
    //role : 3 ,
    rootPath : '/SuiteScripts',
    script : 1234 ,
    deployment : 2
}))
```

Comment: That helps! It seems like now the module is interacting with Netsuite and now I get an error from Netsuite about the restlet called `SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT  - type`. Also the file I'm trying to upload is a json file.

Comment: nscabinet doesn't support JSON but if you edit the Restlet and add json: 'JSON' to the  EXT_TYPES object it will work.

Comment: This worked thanks! The uploaded JSON file was encrypted and I'll have to sort that out but your answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Output console.log(inspect(sendToNetsuite));  It is not defined or not a function.  The repo is private here https://github.com/truecloud-com/nsupload -- maybe contact TrueCloud/Netsuite whatever.

Comment: Ahh I see. Well I started using a different module but I'm getting the error: "SSS_INVALID_SCRIPTLET_ID - That Suitelet is invalid, disabled, or no longer exists." I'll update my question with the details